# nginx location block disables rendering of php files

Tags: regex, nginx, nginx-location

I have this `location` block within my website.conf:

```
 location ~ ^/([^/?&:'"]+)$ {
        try_files $uri @root_path;
    }
```

This part of the file hinders the execution of php files, it always serves them as download.

- How can I exclude *.php files from this regex expression?
- What does that regex even mean?
- Is it even good style to just exclude *.php files in this case?

If somebody could elaborate I would be very grateful.

Some more context: I'm trying out jitsi-meet and I would like to add some php-based functionality to the website.

Comment: The regular expression `location` blocks are evaluated in order. You need to make sure that the `location ~ \.php$` block (or similar) is placed **above** this new block.

Comment: that did the trick - thank you. Do you want to add this as possible answer (even without explicitly answering my questions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression `^/([^/?&:'"]+)$` matches anything that begins with a `/` and contains any character except `/`, `?`, `&`, `:`, `'` and `"`.

The first character is significant as it means it will only match URIs that contain a single path element (e.g. `/foo` and `/index.php`) but will not match URIs that contain another `/` (e.g. `/foo/`, `/foo/bar` and `/foo/index.php`).

The other characters are probably a mistake as `?` and `&` is unlikely to be encountered by a `location` statement as Nginx uses a [normalised URI](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) which has had the query string removed.

---

You do not need to exclude `.php` from this regular expression.

The URIs ending with `.php` are usually processed by another regular expression location block (e.g. `location ~ \.php$`).

Regular expression location blocks are evaluated in order until a match is found, so you need to make sure that the `location ~ \.php$` block is placed **above** the regular expression location block in your question.